# how to add a src image path inside an image tag of another image rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to add an image inside an image tag in rails how to do it?
if i try doing the following code it says the blank.gif is not present   .
how to make it take the asset image part ...  my blank.gif is present in asset/images

```
%img.sp-image{"data-src" => "#{gallery_image.image.url}", :src => "path/to/blank.gif"}/
```

i want to pass blank.gif in src by using something like asset_url so that it directly locates that file rather than giving the entire file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `asset_path` in your HAML

```
%img.sp-image{:alt => "image description", :src => asset_path("blank.gif")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your source location to your file is incorrect, If your image resides in assets/images i.e the default location of images then you need not to write assets/images/image_name instead you can directly do assets/image_name.

> %img.sp-image{"data-src" => "#{gallery_image.image.url}", :src =>
>   "/assets/blank.gif"}/